# Which models are available for the motivic homotopy category $SH^{S^1}(k)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, model-categories, motivic-homotopy

The motivic $S^1$-stable homotopy category  $SH^{S^1}(k)$ (where $k$ is a field that is often assumed to be perfect; yet one can probably take quite general base schemes here) is "intermediate" between the unstable motivic category $H(k)$ and $SH(k)$, and it appears to be rather "unpopular". What are the main references for it and for Quillen model structures underlying it? I have only find a mentioning of one model in Morel's "An introduction to $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy theory"  (after Definition 4.2.2) and I don't know how to "work" with this definition.

One can probably define $SH^{S^1}(k)$ as the localization of the homotopy category of the corresponding spectra of simplicial Nisnevich sheaves (since the latter category is cellular); however, did anybody write this down before me? This approach is also related to the study of the functor $H(k)\to SH^{S^1}(k)$; cf. [Connecting Quillen functors between motivic homotopy categories (of different "types"): references?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268402/connecting-quillen-functors-between-motivic-homotopy-categories-of-different-t)

Comment: Theorem 3.2.5 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5699 constructs such a model category for free and proves many properties, including the existence of model structures on algebras over operads in such spectra.

Comment: I am sorry; this is an abstract statement that does not mention motivic spectra. Do you explain that it can be applied to $SH^{S^1}(k)$  somewhere?

Comment: Motivic spectra are considered in Example 3.4.2, which applies to R_n=(S^1)^{\wedge n} and constructs a model structure for your case.

Comment: I wonder whether anybody compares "their" definitions of motivic stable homotopy categories with any  "standard" ones.:) It appears that you ignore this matter.

Comment: The definition that we use is the same as that of Morel and Voevodsky, which is as standard as it could ever get.  What definition do you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, this definition appears to be "canonical"; yet do you compare it with your construction?

Comment: I am not sure what you have in mind.  Morel and Voevodsky define motivic spaces as the Nisnevich-A^1 localization of simplicial presheaves on the smooth Nisnevich site.  Jardine defines motivic symmetric spectra as symmetric spectra in motivic spaces with respect to (P^1,*).  This is exactly the same construction as in Example 3.4.2, there is nothing to compare.  Or do you have some other definition in mind?

Comment: The problem begins when you pass to specta. Jardine does not prove that one gets Morel's category this way (and says just a few words about $S^1$-spectra).

Comment: Are you referring to Morel's "Some Basic Properties of the Stable Homotopy Category of Schemes"?  In Definition 2.3.1 he defines motivic spectra as nonsymmetric P^1-spectra in simplicial sheaves over the smooth Nisnevich site.  The equivalence to Jardine's model follows from two results: simplicial presheaves are Quillen equivalent to simplicial sheaves (see, e.g., Jardine's book) and nonsymmetric spectra are Quillen equivalent to symmetric spectra (see Hovey's paper).

Comment: Thanks; I will have a look at the paper you mention. I am mostly reading "An introduction to ...". Besides, I need $S^1$-motivic spectra.:)

Comment: Definition 5.1.1 in Morel's "An introduction to A^1-homotopy theory" also uses nonsymmetric spectra in simplicial sheaves, so the above discussion applies.  As for S^1-spectra, the machinery of Jardine and Hovey is fully applicable to S^1 in place of P^1.

Comment: Yes, it is applicable; the question is whether you really obtain the same category.:)

Comment: If you need an equivalence between nonsymmetric S^1-spectra in simplicial sheaves and symmetric S^1-spectra in simplicial presheaves, I can write it up as a short answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need more; I would like to have an equivalence of your/Jardine's definition with section 4.2 of Morel's  "An introduction to A^1-homotopy theory". Do the model structures coincide (if you take the same undelying category); why are the homotopy categories equivalent?

Comment: As about a short answer: could you explain (by a reference) why "spectra of sheaves" are Quillen equivalent to "spectra of presheaves"?

Comment: I looked into Morel's paper.  In Definition 4.1.1 he defines S^1-spectra as nonsymmetric S^1-spectra in simplicial sheaves.  These are Quillen equivalent to symmetric S^1-spectra in simplicial presheaves by the results of Hovey and Jardine.  I will now write up references in an answer if this is what you need.

Comment: Probably the question is whether forming ($S^1$)-spectra commutes with left Bousfield $\mathbb{A}^1$-localization.