# Is $\text{DGA}^{-}$ a monoidal model category?

Tags: homological-algebra, model-categories, differential-graded-algebras

Let $\text{DGA}^{-}$ denote the category of non-positively graded differential graded algebras with differentials of degree $+1$. It is well-known that $\text{DGA}^{-}$ has a model structure with

1. Weak equivalences are quasi-isomorphisms;
2. Fibrations are morphisms that are surjective on all negative degrees;
3. Cofibrations are the morphisms having the left-lifting property with respect to acyclic fibrations.

It is also clear that $\text{DGA}^{-}$ has a tensor product which makes it a monoidal category.

> > My question is: Is the model structure compatible with the tensor product? More precisely, is $\text{DGA}^{-}$ a monoidal model category with the above model structure and tensor product?

Comment: Assuming the tensor product is the tensor product of complexes, $\mathrm{DGA}^-$ is not even closed monoidal.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/a/195194/6249